# The sum of an even integer and an odd integer is always odd. Direct Proof.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I have a direct proof below (must be direct). I was told there is an error and I cannot figure out what the error is. Can someone verify this for me please?

Proof.

```
1. Assume that x is an even integer and y is an odd integer.
2. Claim: x+y is odd
3. By assumption, x = 2k and y = 2k+1 for some integer k.
4. Thus x+y = 2k + 2k + 1 = 2(2k) + 1
5. Thus x+y = 2m + 1 for some integer m
6. Hence, x+y is odd.
```

Comment: The error is: why should it be the same $k$ for $x$ and $y$?

Comment: It should not matter as k is some integer. As long as x, the even number is 2k, and y the odd number is 2k+1, then it should be alright.

Comment: If $x=4=2\times 2$ and $y=7=2\times3+1$, then $k$ cannot simultaneously be $2$ and $3$.

Comment: It certainly is minor, but you nevertheless prove this way that the sum of an even and an odd number is congruent to $1\bmod 4$, which is false. Rather than an error, I would speak of a lack of rigour.

Comment: @Bernard - I am following an example (several examples) from our text book that uses 2k+1 and 2k to express odd and even integers. I do not believe that this is the error I was told I have. The professor has used these a hand full of times in the past for other proofs. Assuming for the purposes of this example that k is a single number and that the use of k for both is valid, do you see anything else that would cause an issue? Order of the statements? Wording / phrasing? An assumption out of place?

Comment: Line 3 is technically not correct. Saying $x=2k$ and $y=2k+1$ for some integer $k$ means that $y=x+1$, which certainly is not necessarily the case. Instead, say something like $x=2k$ and $y=2j+1$ for some integers $k$ and $j$.

Comment: Using $k$ for both is valid, but not in the same equation.

Comment: @Bernard / Math1000 / Chris - I am reviewing all the material now and realizing that he never used them both in the same statement, it was always either one or the other. I am going to assume that this was the issue! Thank you to you all!

Answer (score 2):

Your proof has the right idea, but for the reason pointed out in the comments, it is not actually correct. You have implicitly assumed $x=2k$ and $y=2k+1$ **for the same** $k$, which is not a reasonable assumption. Now, it is perfectly fine to write them independently and say that $x=2k_1$ for *some* $k_1$, and that $y=2k_2+1$ for *some* $k_2$, but when you use the same letter, $k$, for both of them, you are implicitly assuming $k_1=k_2$. This is obviously absurd: for example, $4=2\times 2$ but $7=2\times 3+1$ and $2\neq 3$.

It is not too hard to fix your proof, however. Just write $x=2k_1$ and $y=2k_2+1$, so that $x+y=2(k_1+k_2)+1$, and since $k_1+k_2$ is an integer, this is going to be odd.